# Php session time

Tags: session, php

Have a same problem with php-fpm and Nginx, I  set a session config, on which people want be logged in 7 days from `session_start()`, but this config only work correctly in some computers. Sometimes logout makes in 2 hours, sometime after 1 days - it is completely random. Can anyone help me to correct my config?

My config:

> session.gc_maxlifetime = 604800
>
> session.cookie_lifetime = 604800
>
> session.gc_divisor = 1000
>
> session.cache_expire = 10080
>
> session.cache_limiter = nocache
>
> session.referer_check =
>
> session.gc_probability = 1
>
> session.cookie_domain =
>
> session.cookie_httponly =
>
> session.cookie_path = /
>
> session.use_cookies = 1
>
> session.use_only_cookies = 1
>
> session.save_handler = memcache
>
> session.save_path = "127.0.0.1:11211"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)